# How can I roll bits of two numbers in numpy array to right?

Tags: python, numpy, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a script to transfer bmp image to Delta Electronics HMI (industrial automation touch-panel). Main case here is that HMI uses a little bit strange format of pixels. It looks like 16bit RGB555, but all bits of two bytes of color each pixel are shifted to right, ordered in BRG and green color using 4 bits instead 5.

I write some code, and it seems work ok and image are displaying correctly, but it takes a lot of time to convert 600x250 pix image (around 1.5 seconds).

Eventually, I have a numpy array of two numbers, that I need to roll right, but like one number, not each separately.

```
def img_to_hex(img):
    # swapping green channel with red
    green_ch = img[:, :, 1].copy()
    red_ch = img[:, :, 2].copy()
    img[:, :, 1] = red_ch
    img[:, :, 2] = green_ch

    # decoding to 555 color
    im555 = np.vstack(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR555))

    for ind, i in enumerate(im555):
        # changing bytes order for every pixel
        bits = ''
        im555[ind][0], im555[ind][1] = im555[ind][1], im555[ind][0]

        # converting int to bin
        for num in im555[ind]:
            bits = bits + bin(num)[2:].rjust(8, '0')

        # rotating string
        rot_str = rotate_string(bits, 2)

        # converting bits to int
        im555[ind][0], im555[ind][1] = int(rot_str[:8], 2), int(rot_str[8:], 2)

    img_bytes = im555.tobytes()

    return img_bytes.hex()

def rotate_string(input, d):
    # slice string in two parts to right
    rfirst = input[0: len(input) - d]
    rsecond = input[len(input) - d:]
    return rsecond + rfirst
```

Example result of running this code:

```
[255 127] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape - (2,)
0111111111111111 - original - 0xFF 0x7F
1101111111111111 - rolled - 0xDF 0xFF
[223 255] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape - (2,)

[170  45] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape - (2,)
0010110110101010 - original - 0xAA 0x2D 
1000101101101010 - rolled - 0x8B 0x6A 
[139 106] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> shape - (2,)
```

I also tried to do this with numpy:

```
    for ind, i in enumerate(im555):
        im555[ind][0], im555[ind][1] = im555[ind][1], im555[ind][0]
        im555[ind] = np.packbits((np.roll((np.unpackbits(im555[ind])), 2)))
```

But it takes about 12 seconds to convert 600x250pix image.

So how can I do it quickly?

Answer (score 0):

One might expect numpy to be very fast but there are three discrete operations in your code - i.e., unpack, roll (ROR), pack

Here's a pure Python implementation of ROR that may be useful (also includes timing rig):

```
from random import randint
from time import perf_counter

BITS = 32

values = [randint(0, 2**BITS-1) for _ in range(600*250)]

def ror(n, shift, bits=BITS):
    assert 0 <= n < 2**bits and shift > 0, 'Invalid parameters'
    return n >> shift | (n & 2**shift-1) << bits - shift

start = perf_counter()

for v in values:
    ror(v, 2)

end = perf_counter()

print(f'Duration={end-start:.4f}s')
```

**Output:**

```
Duration=0.0322s
```